# Using generics to refactor

Tags: java, generics

I am used to use generics in typed collections, but I never actually used them to develop something.

I have several classes like this:

```
public class LogInfoWsClient extends GenericWsClient {
    public void sendLogInfo(List<LogInfo> logInfoList) {
        WebResource ws = super.getWebResource("/services/logInfo");
        try {
            String response = ws.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(String.class, new GenericEntity<List<LogInfo>>(logInfoList) {
            });     
    }
}
```

Where the only thing changing between one and another is the service String ("/services/info"), and the type of the list (LogInfo in this case)

I have refactored a couple of methods to a GenericWsClient class, but my objective would be to have something I can use like this:

```
List<LogInfo> myList = database.getList();
SuperGenericClient<List<LogInfo>> superClient = new SuperGenericClient<List<LogInfo>>();
superClient.send(myList,"/services/logInfo");
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it, or even if its possible. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible infact if you look at `java.util.collection` package for example you will find all classes to be parameterzid.

So your class will be something like this

```
public SuperGenericClient<E> {       
    public E getSomething() {
         return E;
    }
}
```

Then to use it you will have

```
SuperGenericClient<String> myGenericClient = new SuperGenericClient<String>();
String something = myGenericClient.getSomething();
```

Extending your example itself your code will look like this:

```
public class SuperGenericClient<E> extends GenericWsClient {
    public void send(List<E> entityList, String service) {
        WebResource ws = super.getWebResource(service);
        try {
            String response = ws.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(String.class, new GenericEntity<E>(entityList) {
            });
        }            
    }
}

public class GenericEntity<E> {
    public GenericEntity(List<E> list){

    }
}
```

You must read [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) for a very good understanding of Generics.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your class like the one below - you can apply the same idea to `GenericEntity`.

```
public class SuperGenericClient<T> extends GenericWsClient {

    public void send(List<T> list, String service) {
        WebResource ws = super.getWebResource(service);
        try {
            String response = ws.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(String.class, new GenericEntity<T>(list) {
            });
        }            
    }
}
```

You can then call it like that:

```
List<LogInfo> myList = database.getList();
SuperGenericClient<LogInfo> superClient = new SuperGenericClient<LogInfo>();
superClient.send(myList,"/services/logInfo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your class like this:

```
public class LogThing<T> {
    public void sendLogInfo(List<T> list) {
        // do thing!
    }
}
```

And when you use it, do so like this:

```
List<LogInfo> myList = db.getList();
LogThing<LogInfo> superClient = new LogThing<LogInfo>();
superClient.sendLogInfo(myList);
```